# ASP.NET site doesn't work on host?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

So, I'm working on an ASP.NET web app (not something I do frequently so I'm very very rusty).  It runs perfectly on my local machine but now that I publish it, it's completely borked.  I've only done 3 pages... two of which are just asp controls and they work fine.  The main page, which has lots of Telerik controls and databinding returns a server error.  I don't think the problem is in the data, since I modified my connection strings to call the remote database when I run the page locally and it works fine from within Visual Studio.  Any suggestions on what I'm overlooking?  Many many thanks for any input!

Comment: what is the error? what did you try to fix? Did you see all necessary assemblies in your publish folder? You need to consider adding more details and examples to get help

Comment: I'm trying to get more detailed debugging information... all I get (at first blush) is a generic server error.  I've tried looking minutely at anything on that page that seems incorrect, but as I say... it runs perfectly on my machine.  Unfortunately this isn't something I do often so I'm in a little over my head and trying to get up to speed quickly... :|

Can you explain (sorry!) a little bit about your comment on the publish folder?  My suspicion is that it's a problem with the Telerik controls.

Comment: When you publish a website, all of your deployment folders/files come to a folder. I hope you are using ASP.Net Publish wizard to publish your website!! If so, browse to that folder, make sure your Telerik Controls are actually copied in to `bin` folder.

Comment: Yes, they are there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy smokes... this was the problem.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/system-invalidoperationexception-not-enough-permissions-inherit-your-page-class-from-radajaxpage-if-you-are-running-under-medium-trust-level

I've used the Telerik controls a number of times and never had an issue with this...maybe a matter of the host?

Comment: Let me guess... Godaddy.

Comment: Yeah... can I blame them for the 2 days ruined chasing this?

Comment: Oo... So this is permission issue? Please ask them to give full permission for you. But it seems that Godaddy don't provide full trust, you need to find other hosting provider that support Full Trust

Comment: @DouglasThomas I have the site set for "full permission", this seems to be some weird GoDaddy idiosyncracy. The Telerik blog solution worked, just wasted a horrible amount of time chasing the problem.

Hope it helps someone else...

Comment: @PaulBinCT2 Nice to hear that. :)